# How to remove extLst from Theme elements in ApachePOI XSSFWorkbook?

Tags: xml, apache-poi, xssf

I need to create theme elements without extLst for XSSFWorkbook. I don't want xml entry `<a:extLst xsi:nil="true"/>` or `<a:extLst />`. ApachePOI creates first of them when extLst is empty and the second one when I call CTBaseStyles.addNewExtLst(). I tried also call CTBaseStyles.unsetExtLst(), but finally xml has `<a:extLst xsi:nil="true"/>`. Is it any way to tell ApachePOI to not create extLst entry?

Comment: I believe that Excel often writes those tags in too. Are you able to explain what the problem with them is?

Comment: For example, Excel2013 doesn't have this entry. In mine I've got theme [link](http://rewres.idl.pl/pm/themes/Berlin.thmx) - probably it is built-in theme, but I'm not sure. And when I create [link](http://rewres.idl.pl/pm/themes/T_2013_Berlin-by-Excel2013.xlsx), theme1.xml doesn't have extLst in theme elements. When I use ApachePOI and create [link](http://rewres.idl.pl/pm/themes/T_2013_Berlin-by-ApachePOI.xlsx), theme.xml has entry `<a:extLst xsi:nil="true"/>` or `<a:extLst />` - and then Excel2013 doesn't select "Berlin".

Comment: When I remove entry (by editing theme-1.xml manually inside XLSX file), I get [link](http://rewres.idl.pl/pm/themes/T_2013_Berlin-by-ApachePOI-modified.xlsx), where "Berlin" is selected in my Excel.
I checked the same for 2007 and 2010, where situation is even worse: If I leave `<a:extLst xsi:nil="true"/>`, Excel can't read Theme at all. To prevent - I use CTBaseStyles.addNewExtLst() to get `<a:extLst />` - but still the best situation is to have no entry.

Comment: Oh, I didn't write what is the main problem: I would like to get XLSX file with Theme recognized by Excel. Now Excel reads all parameters and Theme is usable, but user can't see which Theme is currently used.

Comment: Make sure you're using POI 3.13 beta 2 or later (or nightly build from the last few days). There have been recent theme related fixes in the last few weeks